# what is the correct way to reference image in javascript application

Tags: javascript, html, import, vite

I'm working a js website with file structure like so:
public

| public | src |
| --- | --- |
| image_files | a.html |

in my a.html
i imported an image

```
<img src="/images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt=""/>
```

however, it doesn't seem to be able to locate it.

i tried to import it as

```
<img src="/public/images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt=""/>
```

it still doesn't seem to be able to locate it and i got warning message like so

> Files in the public directory are served at the root path.
> Instead of /public/images/image01.jpg, use /images/image01.jpg. (x2)

And here is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
export default defineConfig({
  // The base path for your application
  // **Explicitly set base path for clarity:**
  base: "./",

  // **Adjust root path if necessary:**
  root: "./src",

  // Development server configuration
  server: {
    // Port number
    port: 3000,

    // Hostname
    host: "localhost",

    // Enable HTTPS
    https: false,
  },

  // Production build configuration
  build: {
    // Adjust the chunk size warning limit as needed
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000,

    // Output directory
    outDir: "dist",

    // Ensure that assets are served relative to the current directory
    assetsDir: "./",

    // Enable/disable minification
    minify: true,

    // Enable/disable CSS code splitting
    cssCodeSplit: true,

    // Configure assets behavior
    assetsInlineLimit: 4096,

    // Configure source map generation
    sourcemap: false,

    // Modify rollup options to include all HTML files in the output directory
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        // Specify all HTML files here dynamically
        ...Object.fromEntries(
          fs
            .readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "src"))
            .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".html"))
            .map((file) => [path.basename(file, ".html"), `src/${file}`])
        ),
        // Add script.js as an entry point
        main: "/js/main.js",
        script: "/js/script.js",
      },
      output: {
        // Ensure your JS files are included in the output directory
        // (e.g., if it's in the "src/js" directory)
        dir: "dist",
        entryFileNames: "[name].[hash].js",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The error message told you EXACTLY what to do.  EXACTLY.  Did you do it?

Answer (score -1):

I would try serving the image path without the `/public`.

In your HTML code, you've referenced an image with the path /public/images/image01.jpg. However, since VBite serves files from the "public" directory directly from the root path, including /public in the file path is redundant.

suggests using `<img src="/images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="">.` or you can use  `./` which refers to the current directory. `../` which refers to the parent directory
`<img src="./images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="">.`

This change will ensure that your code remains consistent with VBite's configuration and best practices.

Comment: Hi @Bruno DaSilva, thank you for the suggestion. 

I tried '<img src="/images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="">.' and '<img src="./images/image01.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="">.'

and I also included '  // The base path for your application
  // **Explicitly set base path for clarity:**
  base: "./",'
in my vite.config.js

none of those methods worked.

Comment: Any time bro! 

Honestly, I don't see any issues with your configuration either.  
1. Inspect the browser to see if the HTML attribute is actually loaded to the page. Also, add a text in your alt attribute so it will display incase the image load fails.

2. If you can or have access to compare projects where images are loaded to the page and see what is different from yours